# Why gcc on Windows assigns a specific value to a variable?

Tags: c, variables

this is my first question so... nice to meet you!
Could someone explain why this code written in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 int choice;

 printf("\nSize of 'choice' %d\n", sizeof(choice));
 printf("Size of 'int' %d\n", sizeof(int));
 printf("Value of 'choice %d\n", choice);
 return 0;
}
```

compiled on Windows using `gcc -o C:\test.exe test.c` (gcc version 2015/06/27) returns these values

```
Size of 'choice' 4
Size of 'int' 4
Value of 'choice 2
```

while on Linux everything works as I expected, returning these values

```
Size of 'choice' 4
Size of 'int' 4
Value of 'choice 0
```

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Undefined behavior, that's what you're missing.

Comment: Accessing an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour (anything can happen)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior/1472/use-of-an-uninitialized-variable#t=20161018123252455759

Answer (score 6):

Uninitialized local non-static variables are just that, *uninitialized*. They will have an *indeterminate* value. Using them without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Yes this is subtle: *uninitialized* is not undefined behavior, we can have *uninitialized* variables, but reading them before setting them leads to *undefined behavior*

Answer (score 3):

In your code you defined a variable without specifying an initial value, so you cannot pretend the variable to be automatically initialized to anything.

If you want your variable to be zero-initialized, please do so explicitly with `=0`.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing?

You never initialise `choice` in the first place. So the behaviour is undefined. It doesn't matter what compiler you are using, the value printed is just garbage value in the memory location of `choice`.

Comment: *undefined behavior* means...undefined. There could be no print, just a crash.

Comment: No there cannot be a crash in this case. Variable `choice` is uninitialised, but it has already been defined, ie it's already allocated a memory location properly. The `printf` merely reads whatever stored in that memory location. There is no pointer or invalid memory access that could lead to a crash.

Comment: Alas, if you read the standard there could be a trap representation inside, say invalid bit settings that is not a valid representation of a value of the type. I know, this is no common, but the fact that that could be, leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You try to use variable without initialization. So, it can contains a random value

Answer (score -1):

The value in the choice variable is not initialized so default value is undefined since it is a automatic storage class and it is different in different platforms